# Not able to display data from post in ionic

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to get data that I get from a post call and display in my html page in ionic.

My Ts code is

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-fashion',
  templateUrl: 'fashion.html',
})
export class FashionPage {
  users: any;
  body: Object = {
    "id": 1014,
    "filter": null,
    "lat": 13.05831,
    "lng": 80.21195,
    "mapRadius": 5,
    "pageSize": 50,
    "pageStart": 1,
    "priceRangeFrom": 0,
    "priceRangeTo": 100000
  };
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.users = this.httpClient.post('myapi',this.body);
    this.users.subscribe(data => {
      this.users = data;
      console.log('my data: ', data);
      console.log("the users data ------------>",this.users);
    })
  }
}
```

And my html page is

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Fashion</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <ion-list inset>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let user of (users | async) ">
      <h2>{{user.Name}}</h2>
      <p>Price : {{user.Price}}</p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

[image]
The error is `InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]`

but i am also getting the data before the error message comes, so when i click on close on the above image i am getting my data, but i need to get it as soon as get into the page
[image]

EDIT1: I am Getting the data only when i switch to a different tab and come back to this

EDIT2: Guys a I forgot to mention what my api returns, It gives me [34]
i.e.

```
[{
  ....
 },
  ..
].
```

Comment: It because of your async pipe in your *ngFor. Do something like this. 
*ngFor="let user of users | async "

Comment: check the async pipe declaration , in my answer

Comment: I did it, but i am still getting the same result as above i.e. I get the data and the error message, so if i close the error message i am getting the data behind it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your `aync` pipe declaration it should be like below . Also you are using the same `users` property to create the Observable and store the data. Create a new property to store the data.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Fashion</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <ion-list inset>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let user of userData | async ">
      <h2>{{user.Name}}</h2>
      <p>Price : {{user.Price}}</p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

edit : create a new property like `userData:any[] = []` in your component as use it like below -

```
export class FashionPage {
  users: any;
  userData:any[] = []
  body: Object = {
    "id": 1014,
    "filter": null,
    "lat": 13.05831,
    "lng": 80.21195,
    "mapRadius": 5,
    "pageSize": 50,
    "pageStart": 1,
    "priceRangeFrom": 0,
    "priceRangeTo": 100000
  };
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.users = this.httpClient.post('myapi',this.body);
    this.users.subscribe(data => {
      this.userData = data;
      console.log('my data: ', data);
      console.log("the users data ------------>",this.userData);
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: did it bro, still i am getting the same thing, get the data along with the error

Comment: @Grijan you are using the same `users` property to create the Observable and store the data. Create a new property to store the data

Comment: All i need to do it declare separate variable for subscribe and to get the data, no need for async, i have posted the code that works below

Answer (score 1):

1. Initialize `users: any;` as `users = []`; since `async` requires an
   `observable` or an `array`
2. Also **change the variable name of subscription**,

   **`this.users = this.httpClient.post('myapi',this.body);`**

   to,

   **`this.userResult = this.httpClient.post('myapi',this.body);`**
3. change html to  `<ion-item *ngFor="let user of users | async ">`

**HTML:**

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let user of users | async ">
      <h2>{{user.Name}}</h2>
      <p>Price : {{user.Price}}</p>
</ion-item>
```

So **TS:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-fashion',
  templateUrl: 'fashion.html',
})
export class FashionPage {
  users: any;
  ....
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.userResult = this.httpClient.post('myapi',this.body);
    this.userResult.subscribe(data => {
      this.users = data;
      console.log('my data: ', data);
      console.log("the users data ------------>",this.users);
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: @Grijan, have you checked this?

Answer (score 1):

The api returns me [34], i.e. array of 34 objects in it.
I needed a separate variable to store the data and to call the api.
So the code that works to get me the data is

HTML code

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Fashion</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <ion-list inset>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let user of userData">
      <h2>{{user.Name}}</h2>
      <p>Price : {{user.Price}}</p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

TS code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-fashion',
  templateUrl: 'fashion.html',
})
export class FashionPage {
  users: any;
  userData = [];
  body: Object = {
    "id": 1014,
    "filter": null,
    "lat": 13.05831,
    "lng": 80.21195,
    "mapRadius": 5,
    "pageSize": 50,
    "pageStart": 1,
    "priceRangeFrom": 0,
    "priceRangeTo": 100000
  };
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.users = this.httpClient.post('myapi',this.body);
    this.users.subscribe(data => {
      this.userData = data;
      console.log('my data: ', data);
      console.log("the users data ------------>",this.userData);
    })
  }
}
```

You guys are always wonderful,this community has never failed me once...Thanks a million to all  for your valuable time to get me the answer!!!!!!!!

Comment: Thanks to Sravan and niladri